# How to get around using global objects in this scenario

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have a program that displays several charts on a TV monitor and these charts get cycled through every 30 seconds or so.

I'm using global objects for each chart that is displayed (so the objects contains some bar, area,line series', and some methods). The reason i have them global is because after the initial sql query is executed (every day at 7am) the data for the charts won't change. I just need to cycle through 20 different charts throughout the day.

Would using local objects be a waste in this scenario? Everytime it is time to switch to a new chart the program would have to create a new object and populate the different series' with datapoints that are always the same.

What can i do to avoid using global objects in this scenario? The reason i'm asking is because i've read that you should keep away from global objects in your programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Global/local objects - its really a matter of encapsulation (and a matter of scope - objects can be application global or class global - best practice is to initialize and assign an object as close to where it is needed, scopewise - and scope can be application (namespace actually), class, method and even block (like using{} or foreach{}). Instead of creating a lot of application global members you should encapsulate them into classes and initialize those classes. First of all you dont clutter your main loop and secondly you have all the advantages of, well classes - subclassing, polymorphism, etc. Keep references to those classes as long as you need them, in your case, as far as I can tell, keep them until the data changes. That would be 24 hours? So what?

At some point your data will need to be accessible from the main application object anyhow. If you encapsulated your data objects nicely, i.e. create some classes that hold all the information you need to display, you will still have to initialize those classes in your main application loop.

I do not think it is necessary to recreate the objects every 30 seconds. Once you populated the class members they dont change, except if *you* change or dispose them of course. Also it seems unlikely to me that they actually hog your computers memory so much that each chart should really get disposed once it was displayed only to get recreated a few seconds or possibly minutes later from data which had to be stored in memory somewhere anyhow.

The way I understand how your app should work I would create a base chart class, create as many chart subclasses as I have charts (if they differ from each other in object design, else just create on class and, possibly put them in a List(), fill each chart at 7am and loop through the collection to display them.

Comment: That List() that contains the chart objects would have to be global wouldn't it? Otherwise it would be eligible for garbage collection after the method it "lives" in has finished executing? It's not a big deal to me if the list is global i'm just trying to learn

Comment: Whether the list should be initialized in your main object kinda depends on how extensive your application is. You can encapsulate it into a class as well and also all business logic, i.e. the timer, the charts, etc. Then, when initializing this class from your main object, it could start the timer and do all the work. In your main object you would only have one line which initializes the class.

Comment: Garbage collection works differently though. It only collects objects that are no longer used - or referenced - no matter the scope. As long as your object is still referenced, or references other objects, it will not be collected. You can stop referencing an object by setting your reference to a null pointer and it will eventually be garbage collected. Mind you this is a very basic explanation but I dont want to confuse you with too much input. MSDN is most of the time a very good ressource though: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088.aspx

Comment: In that case my chart objects would never be eligible for garbage collection since each of the chart objects holds references to the different type of charts that will be displayed on the screen?

Comment: That is right. And that is what you want. Even when you update the charts the next day the chart objects still have the same reference - you only update the members (variables) they reference to - or their values. Actually this is better than reinitializing them again and again, as if you accidentally introduce a memory leak by not dereferencing one of their class members (dont worry too much about this now) it would take months before that would become a problem. If you reinitialize them every 30 seconds that would become a problem far sooner.

Comment: Absolutely - just dont worry about the memory leak stuff for now. The SO comments are not really a great place to explain that and it goes to deep for now.

Comment: Ok. I deleted my previous comment because i didn't want to have too many comments. You have answered my question though Sascha. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Using global objects are to be avoided in large projects because they generally affect the flexibility of the system.

For example, when the business object caches results for 24 hours, it means other parts of the program that may wish to fetch the latest result will end up getting cached values, or it will have to be rewritten.

This problem can be avoided by not using class members, but instance members. e.g.

```
public class ResultsCache
{
  public IEnumerable<Visitors> TotalVisitors {get; }
  public IEnumerable<Purchases> TotalPurchases {get; }
  public IEnumerable<Refunds> TotalRefunds {get; }

  public void FetchData() {
     //...
  }
}

var cache24hours = new ResultsCache();
var currentView = new RefundsView(cache24hours);
```